# Angular library pushing to load all modules of exported members

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-library

I have two modules primeng, material so i wanted to use them in independent angular applications so i started creating a angular library for that and i pushed into npm repository.

so i started creating shared library which is exporting the both primeng, material modules in public_api.ts as follows

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of accsm-common
 */
export * from './lib/modules/material.module';
export * from './lib/modules/primeng.module';
```

Till here is everything is fine.

I am using this shared library in independent angular applications let say app1 & app2

In app1 --> I need both primeng and material module (installed primeng and material as local dependencies in package.json)

In app2 --> I need only material module (installed only material as local dependencies in package.json)

When i install this shared library in app1 & app2.

app1 is working fine as it need both the primeng and material modules

but when it comes to app2 it is throwing error saying

```
Can't resove primeng modules
```

So how to handle this senario with shared library?

Comment: Can you provide more infos on how you try to import the modules in your apps?

Comment: @Eweren i had installed it as npm dependency like any other : npm install accsm-common

Comment: But where do you define or import them? You have to import the modules in the imports array of your apps module

Comment: @Eweren yes i had imported into my app2 app.module.ts as : import { MaterialModule } from 'accsm-common';